# Metodos de conexão em ASP .NET

Tags: entity-framework, linq, code-first, dapper, ado

Sou iniciante em ASP e C#. Tenho dúvidas e este é o real motivo para perguntar aqui. Antes de mandarem ler como é a politica de perguntas entendam que eu sou iniciante e realmente preciso de ajuda.

Eu tenho uma dúvida de **como conectar a minha aplicação ASP com um banco de dados** `DB First`.

---

Como estou iniciando, resolvi levantar o máximo de informações possíveis. Inicialmente li que há dois tipos de projetos: o `Code First` onde  primeiro são desenvolvido as classes e o banco é gerado automaticamente em cima disso e o `Database First`: banco de dados desenvolvido antes da aplicação.

Depois disso comecei a pesquisar como realizar as conexões, logo coletei as seguintes informações:

- Ado .net: Nativo da plataforma .Net. Todos os exemplos que achei foram em cima do `Code First`. Todas as conexões são geradas automaticamente
- Entity Framework: `ORM` fortemente usado em aplicações `code first` e não é aconselhado o uso em aplicações `DB First` pois o código ficaria muito extenso e de difícil compreensão.
- Dapper: Micro ORM, desenvolvido por alguém do `stack overflow`, rápido e eficiente. Aconselhado também para aplicações `Code First`.
- Linq: Diga-se de passagem que seja uma mascara para as strings SQL

---

Porque é tão desaconselhado o uso de todos esses itens em uma aplicação `DB First`?

Comment: DB First é algo que os criadores dos ORM como o EF foi deixado de lado e partiram para aplicação que usam como foco o Code First por isso deve ter visto em muitos lugares se falar que é aconselhável.  O que é aconselhável nem sempre é o que precisamos em nossas aplicações... Sua pergunta é muito confusa... não sei se você quer fazer uma conexão com o banco ou saber a diferença entre code first e db first.

Comment: Então eu tenho que reinventar a roda toda vez? O que acontece quando eu já tenho uma base de dados? Tenho que recriar ela? Inviável...

Comment: Não... Você pode simplesmente criar seu code first fazendo seu mapeamento em cima da sua base de dados existente ...

Comment: veja a documentação https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Mas em alguns sites que li  informaram que este mapeamento torna o código extenso e de difícil compreensão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas acredito que posso te ajudar pois passei por isso há alguns dias.

É importante descentralizar o banco de dados da aplicação. Como isto é feito? Através do Mapeamento realizado em cima da base de dados existente. Sugiro que leia este [tutorial](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2015/03/ef-code-first-partindo-de-uma-base-existente/), vai te esclarecer as suas dúvidas.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, na realidade, nos exemplos que deu ADO é a única forma de conectar ao banco. As outras são ORM's ou micro ORM's, etc.

Ambos utilizarão o ADO para conectar ao banco.

Os ORM's convertem os resultados oriundos do banco em objetos (basicamente). Cabe pesquisa, pois há um outro significado e motivos para a existência de ORM's.

Você não deve utilizar todos na mesma aplicação pois imagine o peso e os conflitos que aconteceriam se tentasse...
O Entity por si só já e bem pesado e bem rígido (até engessado as vezes). Não faz muito sentido misturar com outros, entende?

Com relação ao Db first ou Code first.
**Code first**: Cria-se o banco de acordo com as classes criadas na aplicação. Usa-se o ORM para isso.

**Db First:** O banco já existe e criamos as classes a partir desse banco, as vezes, automaticamente.

Observações: Já pode ter um banco pronto no code first, mas deve tomar muito cuidado quando criar suas classes.